# Jet Access Query not working wildcard not select

Tags: sql, vb.net, dataset, jet

I am using a dataset sql query and trying to populate a reportviewer field however I am not having much luck. It keeps populating everything in the field. all of this stuff is new to me and so I do not even think I am approaching this the right way.

I am trying to select data from a wildcard that is represented by a string variable in vb.net. If I run it in query builder with Class_Schedule.(blah) in the where column it will work. however if  I use the query builder and run it no matter what I put in the parameter it populates the entire field.

```
SELECT        MemberBase.ID, MemberBase.EntireName, Class_Schedule.MemberID
FROM            (MemberBase INNER JOIN
                         Class_Schedule ON MemberBase.ID = Class_Schedule.MemberID)
WHERE        (true = ?)
```

any help is appreciated and sorry for the poor explanation, I have googled and tried various things for 2 hours and I have gotten no where.

**EDIT:**

Here is ideally what I want but it doesnt work:

```
SELECT        MemberBase.ID, MemberBase.EntireName, Class_Schedule.MemberID
FROM            (MemberBase INNER JOIN
                     Class_Schedule ON MemberBase.ID = 
Class_Schedule.MemberID)
WHERE        (Class_Schedule.? = true)
```

Comment: What is WHERE (true=?) intended to do?

Comment: to find WHERE a column under Memberbase named ? is boolean with value true

Comment: The where clause should be something like `WHERE some_column = ?` or `WHERE some_column LIKE ?`. The parameter passed for `?` can only contain a value, not a condition or column names.

Comment: I am trying to make the some_column the question mark. I already know the column is going to be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query parameter placeholder `?` can only accept the values to be compared. If cannot contain column names. If you want to compare different columns, you must use string concatenation to build your query.

```
sql = "SELECT ... WHERE [" & column_name & "] = true"
```

or with the new string interpolation (where `column_name` is a VB string variable):

```
sql = $"SELECT ... WHERE [{column_name}] = true"
```

If you compare against values other than `true`, you should still use parameters for them for safety reasons. See: [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

You cannot pass column names as parameters, but you could use a trick:

```
SELECT ... WHERE (col1 = true OR 0 = ?) AND (col2 = true OR 0 = ?) AND (col3 = true OR 0 = ?)
```

and then you pass the parameter 1 for the column you want to test and 0 for the others.

Comment: Is there any way to parameterize (spelling?) queries in a dataset? I have never gotten it to work with Datasets, but if I am doing a OleDB query I always parameterize it.

Comment: No, you cannot parametrize column names or whole where conditions in SQL. But you could use a trick: `WHERE (col1 = true OR 0 = ?) AND (col2 = true OR 0 = ?) AND (col3 = true OR 0 = ?)` and then you pass the parameter `1` for the column you want to test and `0` for the others.

Comment: Thank you Oliver. I will try to write a Oledb query and go from there.

Comment: `No, you cannot parametrize column names or whole where conditions in SQL`, Yes you can, with dynamic sql.